# NPM install not working unless node_modules folder is first deleted?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops

I have a visual studio team services build definition with a first step of "npm install". This definition deploys to an azure web app.

NPM completes without error, however when visiting the web app, the error "Cannot find module 'express'" is thrown. When running "npm install" manually from the "wwwroot" folder, where the web app files and package.json are located the command completes successfully again, but the error persists.

*However*, when i delete the "node_modules" from within the "wwwroot" folder, and run "npm install" again, the error is gone and the web app functions as intended!

How can I fix my build definition so that these manual steps are not required on every deployment?

The relevant excerpt from my package.json is below:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-alpha7",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
},
```

The npm log is available below:

```
    2016-08-21T01:19:28.9476070Z ##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\tasks\Npm\0.2.15\task.json
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9476070Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\tasks\Npm\0.2.15\task.json
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9486073Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9646119Z ##[debug]check path : C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9656074Z ##[debug]npm=C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9666075Z ##[debug]cwd=C:\a\1\s
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9686074Z ##[debug]path exists: C:\a\1\s
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9696068Z ##[debug]command=install
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9696068Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd arg: install
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9706071Z ##[debug]arguments=null
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9706071Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9716073Z ##[debug]Arguments:
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9716073Z ##[debug]   install
2016-08-21T01:19:28.9726071Z [command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd install
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5330503Z smart-iot@1.0.0 C:\a\1\s
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5330503Z +-- azure-iot-device-amqp@1.0.10
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5340519Z | +-- azure-iot-amqp-base@1.0.10
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5340519Z | | +-- amqp10@3.2.2
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5340519Z | | | +-- node-amqp-encoder@0.0.2 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5350499Z | | | +-- node-int64@0.4.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5350499Z | | | `-- stately.js@1.3.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5360508Z | | `-- amqp10-transport-ws@0.0.3
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5360508Z | |   `-- nodejs-websocket@1.6.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5370502Z | `-- azure-iot-device@1.0.10
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5370502Z |   `-- azure-storage@1.1.0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5370502Z |     `-- readable-stream@2.0.6
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5380497Z |       +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5380497Z |       `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5390498Z +-- express@4.14.0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5390498Z | +-- accepts@1.3.3
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5390498Z | | `-- mime-types@2.1.11
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5400508Z | |   `-- mime-db@1.23.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5400508Z | +-- array-flatten@1.1.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5420690Z | +-- content-disposition@0.5.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5420690Z | +-- cookie-signature@1.0.6 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5430497Z | +-- debug@2.2.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5430497Z | | `-- ms@0.7.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5440674Z | +-- depd@1.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5440674Z | +-- escape-html@1.0.3 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5450502Z | +-- etag@1.7.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5450502Z | +-- finalhandler@0.5.0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5460530Z | | `-- unpipe@1.0.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5460530Z | +-- fresh@0.3.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5470497Z | +-- merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5470497Z | +-- methods@1.1.2 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5480496Z | +-- on-finished@2.3.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5480496Z | | `-- ee-first@1.1.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5490499Z | +-- parseurl@1.3.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5490499Z | +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5500513Z | +-- proxy-addr@1.1.2
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5500513Z | | `-- forwarded@0.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5500513Z | +-- send@0.14.1
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5510491Z | | +-- destroy@1.0.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5510491Z | | `-- mime@1.3.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5520499Z | +-- type-is@1.6.13
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5520499Z | | `-- media-typer@0.3.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5520499Z | `-- utils-merge@1.0.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5530492Z `-- pug@2.0.0-beta4
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5530492Z   +-- pug-code-gen@0.0.7 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5540495Z   | +-- doctypes@1.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5540495Z   | +-- js-stringify@1.0.2 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5540495Z   | +-- pug-attrs@2.0.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5550503Z   | `-- void-elements@2.0.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5550503Z   +-- pug-filters@1.2.3
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5550503Z   | +-- clean-css@3.4.19
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5560494Z   | | `-- source-map@0.4.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5560494Z   | |   `-- amdefine@1.0.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5570499Z   | +-- jstransformer@1.0.0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5570499Z   | | +-- is-promise@2.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5570499Z   | | `-- promise@7.1.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5580491Z   | +-- pug-walk@0.0.3 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5580491Z   | +-- resolve@1.1.7 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5590498Z   | `-- uglify-js@2.7.0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5590498Z   |   +-- source-map@0.5.6 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5590498Z   |   +-- uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5600495Z   |   `-- yargs@3.10.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5600495Z   |     +-- camelcase@1.2.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5600495Z   |     +-- cliui@2.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5610497Z   |     | +-- center-align@0.1.3 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5610497Z   |     | | +-- align-text@0.1.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5620497Z   |     | | | +-- kind-of@3.0.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5620497Z   |     | | | | `-- is-buffer@1.1.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5620497Z   |     | | | +-- longest@1.0.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5630568Z   |     | | | `-- repeat-string@1.5.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5630568Z   |     | | `-- lazy-cache@1.0.4 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5640500Z   |     | +-- right-align@0.1.3 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5640500Z   |     | `-- wordwrap@0.0.2 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5640500Z   |     +-- decamelize@1.2.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5650495Z   |     `-- window-size@0.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5650495Z   +-- pug-lexer@2.0.2
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5660502Z   | +-- character-parser@2.2.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5660502Z   | | `-- is-regex@1.0.3 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5660502Z   | `-- is-expression@2.1.0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5670500Z   |   `-- object-assign@4.1.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5670500Z   +-- pug-parser@2.0.1
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5670500Z   | `-- token-stream@0.0.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5680491Z   `-- pug-strip-comments@0.0.1 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5680491Z     `-- pug-error@0.0.0 
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5820489Z ##[debug]rc:0
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5820489Z ##[debug]success:true
2016-08-21T01:19:43.5830501Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded
2016-08-21T01:19:43.6100505Z Finishing task: Npm
```

As an example, the "express" module folder is missing its "index.js", "LICENCE" and "package.json" files for an unknown reason.

Comment: Please provide relevant text from any logs **in the question body**.  It is not appropriate to ask people to download an unknown file from a random URL.  This will either draw negative attention to the question or cause the question to be ignored entirely.  Also, the question is less relevant to others in the future if it relies upon files that might later not exist.

Comment: Understood, modifying as requested now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried on my side, leveraging **npm install**>**Archive files**>**Copy and Publish build Artifact**>**Azure Web App Deployment** work flow to install the package, package the application and deploy to Azure Web App.

[image]

And here are the detailed build steps' parameters:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

And you can refer to https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/release/examples/nodejs/node-to-azure-webapps#build for more info about the building and deploying work flow in VSTS in similar scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer, a slight variant of this where "Prefix root folder to name to archive paths" was unticked solved my problem!